# jQuery converts <td> field value into anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm experiencing a very weird bug in a web app I wrote. If I run it on a computer (windows/linux/ios) than it doesn't have this problem. However when I run it in an iPhone or an iPad I get a `NaN` in a specific place.

So I want to calculate a percentage of a given value. This is how I capture the `td` fields in js:

```
var total_vend = document.getElementById("tot_vend").innerHTML;
var max_production = document.getElementById("tot_max").innerHTML;
```

Pretty standard. Afterwards, to calculate the percentage, I use:

```
num = Math.floor(total_vend / max_production * 100);
text = num + "%"; //allows me to had the percentage symbol to the number
```

Here is where it gets tricky. I've got 4 places where this is run (4 different accounts with different values). In only one of the sessions I get `NaN`.

I've proceded to `alert()` both `total_vend` and `max_production` and in `total_vend` I have the correct value, however in `max_production` I get an anchor tag: `<a href="tel:1367520">1367520</a>` and the value it contains it's the value that I need to calculate my percentage.

The `table` where the values are read:

```
<table id="totais_ano">
    <tr>
        <th>TProd</th>
        <th>TVend</th>
        <th>TMax</th>
        <th>TPass</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="tot_prod"><?php echo $total_prod; ?></td>
        <td id="tot_vend"><?php echo $total_vend; ?></td>
        <td id="tot_max"><?php echo $total_max; ?></td>
        <td id="tot_vend_passado"><?php echo $total_pass; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone explain to me what the hell is happening in my code? Like I said this only happens when I access a specific account in my web app using either an iPhone or an iPad.

Comment: have you tried parsing the values using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` before getting the `var num`

Comment: Even i have the same issue on mac at times it returns NaN value:(

Comment: Yes, I have @roullie

Comment: I think your main problem is assuming innerHTML will retrieve something you can typecast to a string. If you are receiving back anchor tags textContent may be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total_vend = document.getElementById("tot_vend").innerHTML;
var max_production = document.getElementById("tot_max").innerHTML;
```

These two variables contain a string. You need to convert their value to integers like so :

```
var total_vend = parseInt(document.getElementById("tot_vend").textContent);
var max_production = parseInt(document.getElementById("tot_max").textContent);
```

Moreover, if `max_produtions` equals 0, the division will fail (can't divide by 0). Be sure to handle this possibility ;)

Comment: That doesn't work, I get `NaN`. I do that afterwards.

`max_productions` gets the value: `<a href="tel:1367520">1367520</a>`

Comment: textContent should not return this kind of value.

Comment: Oh yeah, I only saw the `parseInt()`. With the `.textContent` it works like I intended! Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. Don't forget to mark your question as answered if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should change it to `.textContent` instead:

```
var max_production = document.getElementById("tot_max").textContent.trim();
```

A simple test here:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('phone').textContent.trim();

alert(a);
```

```html
<div id='phone'><a href="tel:1367520">1367520</a></div>
```

*As a sidenote i would say that you should trim() the values for removing the leading/trailing spaces.*

Comment: It's worth noting this is IE9+

Comment: This will most likely be used by iPhones/iPads and Androids so I'm risking the IE9+ for now, and then will try and detect the browser and use the `.innerhtml` for IE.

Also the `.textContent` works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code for the values captured from `td`

```
var total_vend = document.getElementById("tot_vend").innerHTML;
total_vend = parseInt(total_vend);
var max_production = document.getElementById("tot_max").innerHTML;
max_production = parseInt(max_production);
```